Lizmap / QGIS Server Opening Project Issues
I'm currently working on making work Lizmap on a Debian VM. So I've already correctly opened a QGIS project on Lizmap using PostGIS layers, but I had slowdowns with this project due to cache not working properly, which I didn't find any solution (maybe I'll need another question for this one!).
So I tried to use pg_tileserv to create a project with vector tiles layers instead of PostGIS layers because I think (I'm still not sure about that) that this will make the network requests faster and easier, which would be an alternative solution of my cache issue.
So I've activated WMTS on every vector tiles layers of my new project (there is no other modifications). I take advantage of this post because I also had a problem of styling these layers. I've tried to copy and paste the former PostGIS layer style to vector tiles layer but the "keyword  were missing" so IDK if you know about this issue too.
Anyway, so I've generated my lizmap configuration file using the Plugin and then I've copy and paste the project and configuration files in my lizmap repository and I've tried to open it.
Then I get an error and if I try to GetCapabilities, I get this :
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
<ServiceException code="Error"> Server Error ! </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>

If I open my QGIS server logs , I get this :
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'

So few logs can't really help me understanding my issue...
So I was wondering : Is it just impossible to use vector tiles layers with QGIS Server? Or is it caused by another thing?
For more information about the environnement :
My project is composed of 7 vector tiles layers and 1 OSM View
These vector tiles are stored in my local PostgreSQL database.
I use LWC 3.7.6
QGIS Desktop 3.36.2
QGIS Server 3.22.16
